# SVN commit with Eclipse

Tags: svn

I am currently working with SVN in Eclipse.

I switched to an older version of my project and started making changes to that older version.
Now if I commit, will the changes be recorded as new version or will it change this older version, without forming a new version?

Example: My latest version is 70. Switched to 68. Made changes.
Will it create new version '71'? or a changed '68'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion is going to require that you perform an update to merge your changes with the most recent revision before letting you commit them. The new revision is going to be 71.

Comment: Will the 68th version remain the same? or will it change too? I want it to be the same.

Comment: Once a revision is committed there is virtually no way of modifying it. Even if you do `svn delete` it won't go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a branch and start working from that version.

Branching means creating a new line of development on the repository location. This may be useful in a different cases, for example if different clients wish to get the same product but with some differences in functionality.